# How do I get a outer loop in a polar plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, polar-coordinates

To display the multiple microphone directive pattern, I wrote a simple MATLAB program.

```
% Super-cardiod = 0.57
% Hyper-Cardiod = 0.33

A_sen = 20.0;                   % sensitivity 
c = 343;                        % speed of sound 343 m/s
Beta_1 = 0.33;                  % beta value for the shape of the directivity pattern
Beta_2 = 0.57;                  % beta value for the shape of the directivity pattern
d = 0.09;                       % distance between two microphones
Ang_freq = 90;                  % Angular frequency of sound  
theta = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi);   % Angular ref to microphone

U_total_1 = (A_sen *(Ang_freq*d)/c)*(Beta_1+cos(theta));
U_total_2 = (A_sen *(Ang_freq*d)/c)*(Beta_2+cos(theta));

subplot(2,1,1),polar(theta,U_total_1)
subplot(2,1,2),polar(theta,U_total_2)
```

The MATLAB program works to display the directivity pattern as below,

[image]

However, I'd like the inner loop to be an outer loop as shown in the link below.

https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/29895/microphone-pick-up-patterns-for-live-performance-advantages-disadvantages-of-c

I suppose this is due to the axes limits. But I'm not sure. How do I get the inner loop to show as an outer loop. Thank you.

Note: I am using R2014b. Therefore I don't have the polarplot function. So I will have to stick to the polar function in MATLAB.

Comment: Try replacing `polar(theta,U_total_1)` with `polar(theta,abs(U_total_1))`

Comment: Hey, thank you. that worked. If I can get greedy here, do you know if there is another way to change the axes limits, I'd like to be able to display the negative values as well. I know it is possible using the new 'polarplot' function, but is there a way to do so with the 'polar' function?

Comment: No. From the documentation (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polar.html): Negative r values reflect through the origin, rotating by pi (since (theta,r) transforms to (r*cos(theta), r*sin(theta))). If you want different behavior, you can manipulate r prior to plotting. For example, you can make r equal to `max(0,r)` or `abs(r)`.

Comment: Okie dokie. Thanks a bunch.